# startup, renting an expensive house, founders, taxation

Tags: united-states, taxes, start-up

A startup has 4 people.

The startup rents a huge, luxurious house (10k / month rent).

The founders live there.

At this point, can the startup deduct the rent of the house (as an business expense since the office is also there), or does the startup have to pay taxes on the rent because it's a benefit to the founders.

The founders are working 80/hour weeks -- so the house is pretty much always used for business rather than personal.

Thanks!

Comment: What country are we talking about.

Comment: Why do you ask? If it's your startup, ask your lawyer/accountant. If you just work there and you're worried your employer is gaining some unfair benefit, go join another firm now, things will get worse before they get better.

Comment: @Dheer: United States.

Comment: @KateGregory : We are about to start the company and am doing background reading before hiring an tax accountant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The founders almost certainly owe tax on the "income" represented by the rent they aren't being charged. It isn't clear whether the corporation also owes income tax on the rent it is not receiving back from them.

You definitely want advice from a paid tax accountant, not least because that helps protect everyone should this arrangement be challenged.